# How do I extract the value_type from template parameters (std::vector and plain pointer)?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a sort with the following interface:

```
template< class RandomIt >
void my_sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last )
{

}
```

I expect `RandomIt` to be an iterator from `std::vector<T>.begin()/end()` or a plain pointer-type `T* first,T* last`.  I think if I assume `RandomIt` is a vector, I can get it from `RandomIt::value_type`, but then this will not work for `T* first,T* last`.

My question is, how can I extract the `value_type T` from the template parameter in both cases?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `iterator_traits<T>::value_type` ([cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits)). Note that the standard library provides iterator_traits definitions for `T*` and `const T*`, so it also works on plain pointers.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using C++11, you can apply `decltype` on the iterator itself to get the `value_type`:

```
typedef decltype(*first) value_type;
```

Note `iterator_traits` may not work for programmer-defined types if the programmer doesn't specialize `iterator_traits` for his iterators, or he doesn't define iterator meeting Standard requirements.

However, the `decltype` trick will work even then.

Comment: `decltype` doesn't tell you the `value_type` of the iterator. The type of `*first` is required to be convertible to the `value_type` but is not required to be identical. Usually it is not identical, it's a reference type. If `iterator_traits` doesn't work for the type then it is not an iterator (although as you say, its author might have intended it to be one and failed to achieve that).

Comment: Maybe you could run the result of decltype through std::remove_reference<decltype(*first)>?

Comment: There's no need for the programmer to specialize `iterator_traits` for her iterators. It is only necessary that the iterator have a `value_type` typedef member, (which could be done by inheriting from an instantiation of `std::iterator`). Failing to do so will prevent the types from being used by standard algorithms, so it really is pretty well obligatory. Also, what Steve Jessop said.

Comment: @rici: I did say that too "*[...] or he doesn't define iterator meeting Standard requirements.*"

Comment: @nawaz, yes you did. But what if the programmer did meet the standard requirements (at least for input iterators) and used a proxy iterator like `std::vector<bool>`? At least on my system (gcc 4.7.2 with libstdc++), `std::cout << sizeof(*std::vector<bool>(1).begin()) << ' ' << sizeof(typename std::vector<bool>::iterator::value_type) << std::endl;` prints `16 1`.

Comment: @rici:  `std::vector<bool>` is a bad example anyway; it is **not** a *container* to begin with.

Comment: @nawaz, yes, i know. But a type without iterator_traits is not an iterator. So it comes down to "which standard violation will you support? The one which practically no standard algorithm supports, or the one used by the `std::vector<bool>`?" And maybe we just disagree about the answer to that question.

Comment: @rici: I think my answer says what I needed to say. :-) I'm not arguing what is iterator, or what is not.